# Create a firestore doc for each auth user in Nextjs (only using sign in with Google)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a user auth system with Nextjs

I am trying to create a document within firestore for each user in my firebase authentication system. I was easily able to do this in previous projects when creating an account with email and password but with the 'sign in with google' feature I can't seem to figure out how.

I don't want to create a new document every time the user logs in..

**My only idea is this:**

When user signs in, loop through all firestore documents and see if the users e-mail matches any firestore doc email. If not, create document, else return.

I feel like there is another way though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why you should not use the `onAuthStateChanged` event on `auth`. A write would cost you the same as a read to check if the data is already there. But with a read you would sometimes need also a write. In total only writes every time come less expensive in read/write actions.

Just listen to auth state changes and update your `firestore` data each time it changes:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
  if (user) {
      await firebase.firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .set(data, {merge:true});
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
```

Make sure to use `set` with `merge` turned on. That will ensure that the data will be created if it doens't exist and update only the field you want to update.

Also make sure to store the data under the user `uid`. With that you ensure that each user has an unique idenfier. It is a bad practice to store users under the `email`. One of the reasons for that is that emails could have chars that are not supported as keys so would need to remove those when saving and add them again when reading the keys.

Comment: This works perfectly except for that all key values in my data object are overwritten upon login. 

For example:
When a user logs in, his role is set to { role: 'editor' }. Somewhere along the line he gets promoted to {role: admin}, but if he logs out and logs back in, the .set(data, {merge:true}) will make him an editor again.

Comment: Can you remove the alue of `role` from data? If you set it from somewhere else don't set it during `onAuthStateChanged`. Then the actual value should stay as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to make a custom hook that can be used anywhere across the application.

First in the _app file inside useeffect hook simply try to get the data from doc if data exist well it means user document is already there and if data does not exists, we need to create a document for that, quite simple. Let's see the code now

> Make sure you read comments written inside the code to better understand

In _app.js,

```
useEffect(async () => {
// now this checks if user is logged in or not
 const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
// if logged in it simply passes the userAuth object to handle user profile 
// which is a custom hook to check if document for this user pre-exist or not! 
// if there wont be any document it will go and create a document and return 
// that document.
// If already there is a document created it will simply return that.
        const userRef = await handleUserProfile(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
// later you can save currentUsr value in any of the state to use it later
          const currentUsr = {
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data(),
          };
          }
        });
      } 
      }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Now the custom hook to check if document is already there or not, here comes the tricky part.

```
export const handleUserProfile = async (userAuth) => {
// as a second check it check if falsy values are returned
  if (!userAuth) return;
  const { uid } = userAuth;

// first it tries to get data from that uid
  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);

  const snapshot = await userRef.get();

// checks if snapshot exist
  if (!snapshot.exists) {
// if snapshot does not exist, it will simply create a document with document
// name as this 'uid'

    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const timeStamp = new Date();

    try {
// making use of same userRef that we created above to create 
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt: timeStamp,
      });
    } catch (error) {}
  }
// if snapshot exist it will simply return the userRef which contains the 
// document only.
  return userRef;
};
```

Voila! :)

Answer (score 0):

Firestore won't create duplicate docs if created when signing in with Google.. so this works:

```
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
fire
  .auth()
  .signInWithPopup(google_provider)
  .then((result) => {
    /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
    var credential = result.credential;

    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    var token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  })
  // CREATE USER DATA IN FIRESTORE
  .then(async () => {
    const data = {
      //ADD DATA HERE
    };
    await fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(fire.auth().currentUser.email)
      .set(data);
  });
```

};